# Android - Facebook SDK 3 - How to login programmatically without LoginButton

Tags: android, button, authentication, facebook-android-sdk

I am writing an app that integrates with Facebook SDK, to share some (string) content as a wall post. Now, I made the HelloFacebookSample work. However It uses their LoginButton to log the user in.

I don't want that. All I want to do is click my share button in the actionbar and share it to facebook. Therefore I want to login programmatically, I tried to emulate what the LoginButton does but no success so far. I get

> 12-06 15:34:33.180: E/AndroidRuntime(19493):
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Session: an attempt was made
>   to reauthorize a session that has a pending request.

public class MainActivity extends FacebookActivity {

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = new ArrayList<String>() {
    {
        add("publish_actions");
    }
};
private final int REAUTHORIZE_ACTIVITY = 3;
private Button postStatusUpdateButton;
private PendingAction pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;

private enum PendingAction {
    NONE, POST_PHOTO, POST_STATUS_UPDATE
}

/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    postStatusUpdateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.postStatusUpdateButton);
    postStatusUpdateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "onClick");
            onClickPostStatusUpdate();
        }

    });

}

@Override
protected void onSessionStateChange(SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    super.onSessionStateChange(state, exception);
}

private interface GraphObjectWithId extends GraphObject {
    String getId();
}

private void showPublishResult(String message, GraphObject result, FacebookRequestError error) {
    String title = null;
    String alertMessage = null;
    if (error == null) {
        title = getString(R.string.success);
        String id = result.cast(GraphObjectWithId.class).getId();
        alertMessage = getString(R.string.successfully_posted_post, message, id);
    } else {
        title = getString(R.string.error);
        alertMessage = error.getErrorMessage();
    }

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(title).setMessage(alertMessage).setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok), null);
    builder.show();
}

private void onClickPostStatusUpdate() {
    Log.d("MainActivity", "onClickPostStatusUpdate");
    performPublish(PendingAction.POST_STATUS_UPDATE);
}

private boolean hasPublishPermission() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    return session != null && session.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions");
}

private void performPublish(PendingAction action) {
    Log.d("MainActivity", "peformPublish");

    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (session == null) {
        session = new Session.Builder(this).setApplicationId("xxx").build();
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
    }

    if (!session.isOpened()) {
        Session.OpenRequest openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest(this);
        openRequest.setPermissions(PERMISSIONS);
        openRequest.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_WITH_FALLBACK);
        session.openForPublish(openRequest);
    }

    if (session != null) {
        // postStatusUpdate();
        pendingAction = action;
        if (hasPublishPermission()) {
            // We can do the action right away.
            handlePendingAction();
            // postStatusUpdate();
        } else {
            // We need to reauthorize, then complete the action when we get
            // called back.
            Session.ReauthorizeRequest reauthRequest = new Session.ReauthorizeRequest(this, PERMISSIONS)
                    .setRequestCode(REAUTHORIZE_ACTIVITY).setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_WITH_FALLBACK);
            session.reauthorizeForPublish(reauthRequest);
        }
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("incomplete-switch")
private void handlePendingAction() {
    PendingAction previouslyPendingAction = pendingAction;
    // These actions may re-set pendingAction if they are still pending, but
    // we assume they
    // will succeed.
    pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;

    switch (previouslyPendingAction) {
    case POST_STATUS_UPDATE:
        postStatusUpdate();
        break;
    }
}

private void postStatusUpdate() {
    // if (user != null && hasPublishPermission()) {
    if (hasPublishPermission()) {
        // final String message = getString(R.string.status_update,
        // user.getFirstName(), (new Date().toString()));
        final String message = "kks uz nemam nervy";
        Request request = Request.newStatusUpdateRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), message,
                new Request.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        showPublishResult(message, response.getGraphObject(), response.getError());
                    }
                });
        Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
    } else {
        pendingAction = PendingAction.POST_STATUS_UPDATE;
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d("MainActivity", "onActivityResult");
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

}

Well, this is still the HelloFacebookSample project which im trying to bend the right way. The only thing I've played with is the performPublish method, stuff with creating the session.

Hope there is an easier way tho!
P.S.: **I am using Facebook SDK 3**

Comment: I am having the same issue, how did you fix it?

Comment: Note that in recent versions of the SDK `Session.ReauthorizeRequest` doesn't exist anymore. You can find an updated working example based on this code [here](https://gist.github.com/sgdesmet/8007039)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Is what you posted your entire Activity?

You also need to override onActivityResult, and pass the values to Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(...). Otherwise, the Session won't know that the user has authorized your app, and that's why you see the error (Session thinks that there's still a pending auth request, which is why you can't reauthorize for publish).

Comment: I posted the full source code, but the code in performPublish is just mended, I have no idea what I am doing really...exposing appId etc. ..(isnt there a normal way to login programmatically?) ..maybe I should step back a bit, how do I only login programatically, without posting a status update?

Comment: Ah, the problem in your code is that in your performPublish method, you're opening the session, then immediately also doing a reauthorize at the same time. If you add a return; after your session.openForPublish call, that should fix things. Alternatively, you can also have a look at the FriendPickerSample (in the FriendPickerSampleActivity) to see how you can open a session without any button presses or UI at all.

Comment: thanks for your help, I will look into this later because I implemented the 2.0 sdk for now as I am going to production soon and 3.0 is still beta anyways. (tho I implemented the 2.0 in like and hour with studying, and much less code ... o well)

Comment: Personally I think that the new API, or the example/tutorials maybe, are really terrible. At least at my eyes. I ended by copying the ENTIRE scrumptious tutorial in my app to do what I wanted to do, and 95% of that tutorial is dealing with fragments, layouts, activities, and other stuff that nothing has to do with the core point: make that API work. What should be easy has become horribly complex, without any real need to be so. I wonder if they're going to really abandon the deprecated Facebook object, without making something clearer before.

Comment: I tried implementing the FB login flow with the UILifeCycleHelper and in certain instances, the `data` param which would normally have a field `mMap`, which contains the FB response, is null.  Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Took me 2 days to find this answer, this step should be stated in their tutorial

Comment: @MingLi - Can you Suggest me any Working code With New Sdk or Old Facebook login,logout,Get profile information(Email,Firstname). this thinks need in my Application. i have tried many codes not working properly all these three. I strucked from last one week, please help me.

Comment: I've just started using the Facebook API coming from API's like Parse.. They need to fire there Android developers, possibly the worst API I've ever used.

Answer (score 18):

Since I had the same feeling as many here who upvoted the @Beppi's comment to @Ming Li answer, and since I use Facebook SDK in my apps, I decided to create more simplified API level which is based on latest Facebook SDK 3.0.b.

The open source library: **android-simple-facebook**
https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook

To your question: **`How to login programatically?`**

1. Set login/logout listener

   ```
   // set login / logout listener
   OnLoginOutListener onLoginOutListener = new SimpleFacebook.OnLoginOutListener()
   {

       @Override
       public void onFail()
       {
           Log.w(TAG, "Failed to login");
       }

       @Override
       public void onException(Throwable throwable)
       {
           Log.e(TAG, "Bad thing happened", throwable);
       }

       @Override
       public void onThinking()
       {
           // show progress bar or something to the user while login is happening
           Log.i(TAG, "In progress");
       }

       @Override
       public void onLogout()
       {
           // change the state of the button or do whatever you want
           Log.i(TAG, "Logged out");
       }

       @Override
       public void onLogin()
       {
           // change the state of the button or do whatever you want
           Log.i(TAG, "Logged in");
       }
   };

   // set the listener
   mSimpleFacebook.setLogInOutListener(onLoginOutListener);
   ```
2. On click of any view, just call `login(Activity)` method

   ```
   mSimpleFacebook.login(MainActivity.this);
   ```
3. To logout call `logout()` method. Like this:

   ```
   mSimpleFacebook.logout();
   ```

How to set **permissions** before login, see very friendly explanation [**here**](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook#usage).

Hope it could be helpful to someone :)

Comment: Really useful library! Saved me many hours. Thank you for making it available.

Comment: Thanks. The Facebook SDK was/is and will always be terribly bad. I have no idea what the Architect had in mind when he designed the API, but he clearly had a very strange vision. The result is a lot of crappy Android apps that constantly (and randomly) fail or throw cryptic messages.

Comment: This is good!  Just wish it supported publishing via graph api.

Comment: @Kon it suppots publishing of feed, photo, video and score via graph api

Comment: @sromku I did figure this out after a bit more time last night. But I was looking for Like support. I see there is a pull request with Like support added in. Hoping it'll make it main branch soon.

Comment: Useful and smart, thanks!   Note, you have to check postId is not null in OnPublishListener - onComplete to be successful.

Answer (score 1):

Great piece of code, thanks.

Please note that with v3 SDK version, the reauthorize code must be replaced with:

```
Session.NewPermissionsRequest reauthRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(FacebookActivity.this, PERMISSIONS)
                                .setRequestCode(REAUTHORIZE_ACTIVITY)
                                .setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_WITH_FALLBACK);
                        session.requestNewPublishPermissions(reauthRequest);
```