# App login using facebook

Tags: android, facebook

Anybody know how to log in in app using native facebook app, without using login dialog? Please help. Using  DEFAULT_AUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE doesn't help.
I want that if facebook app is installed on device, facebook app login activity will be opening instead login dialog.

Comment: If you use Facebook in your app for the first time the login dialog will always been shown. Only if you (or the user) have logged in before, this session will be recognized and used (without showing the dialog again).

Comment: The SDK uses the native facebook app for SSO by default if it's available. What behavior are you seeing? Can you share your code and repro steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to facebook sdk3.0 the first priority is given to native app.The native app takes
 care of the sso.

The login dialog is the fallback method if facebook app is abbsent.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want your Android app to automatically login to Facebook 3.0 without displaying a login button to the user.

If this is the case, then this is what you are looking for:

[Android - Facebook SDK 3 - How to login programmatically without LoginButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13746124/android-facebook-sdk-3-how-to-login-programatically-without-loginbutton)

Comment: Not really. I want that if facebook app is installed on device, facebook app login activity will be opening instead login dialog.