# Facebook android sdk take only the login logic

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-3.0

I want to use the login logic of facebook android sdk, I don't want to make any changes to my manifest so I can't add activities, I also don't want to add resources, or to use android support v4, Is it possible? I'll implement my own custom ui for asking user if he accept to connect.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the features of SDK 3.0 , you can use LoginButton class to automate much of the login process. However, as you said you don't want to modify manifest or add activity, the only option left to you is complete programmatic based login.

See here for such references:

[Facebook authentication without login button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135885/facebook-authentication-without-login-button)

[Android - Facebook SDK 3 - How to login programmatically without LoginButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13746124/android-facebook-sdk-3-how-to-login-programatically-without-loginbutton)